# how to restricts the number of character and lines reads from a file before insertinting into 2dimentional array in java

Tags: java, arrays

i have go through the previous answers but nothing like what i am looking for, specifically in java. here is my code, the block of my code can read a singe character integer only which is not exactly what i intend to do, i intends to reads more than one char integer, it doesn't work. and i want reads only 16 lines and 16 integers in a line from the file even if the file contains more than 16 lines and more than 16 integers per line. can some one share an idea with me please?

Here is sample input data:

```
13 20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 11 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 5 0 0 11 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 333 4  0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 10 41 3 5 8

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 11 2 333 4 
13 20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 11 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 5 0 0 11 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 333 4  0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 10 41 3 5 8
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 11 2 333 4 
13 20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 11 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 5 0 0 11 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 333 4  0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 10 41 3 5 8
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 11 2 333 4 
13 20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 11 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 5 0 0 11 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 333 4  0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 10 41 3 5 8
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 11 2 333 4
```

i just want insert this into the 2dimentional array as you can see in my code, but my array is 16X16 but the file may be more than 16x16 in size, but i just want reads just 16x16 even if the file contains more than that, and ignore the empty line even if it exist.

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"));
String line = null;
int[][] board = new int[16][16]; 
int k = 0; 
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) { 
String[] newmatrix = line.split(" "); 
for(int i=0; i<9; i++) { 
board[k][i] = Integer.parseInt(newmatrix[i]); 
} 
k++;
 }
```

Comment: Can you please tell more about what are you trying to achieve. Please provide details like sample input, desired output and what is going wrong with your current implementation.

Comment: yes sure, here is sample input data:

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be "a learning exercise".  So, hints / advice only<sup>1</sup>:

1. To stop reading after 16 lines, use a counter.
2. Skip an empty line by *testing* for an empty line.
3. Use a `Scanner` (`hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()` to process each line.
4. It is a good idea to avoid hard-wiring literal constants into your code ... like `9` which you seem to have pulled out of the air.
5. Use `board.length - 1` or `board[i].length - 1` for your array bounds when "looping".  (See previous)

Also ... your input file seems to only have 14 integers per line, not 16 as the question states.

---

<sup>1 ... because you will learn more by coding this yourself.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

The code below should work.

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"));
String line = null;
int[][] board = new int[16][16]; 
int k = 0; 
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) { 
    String[] newmatrix = line.split(" "); 
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) { 
        board[k][i] = Integer.parseInt(newmatrix[i]); 
    } 
    k++;
    if (k == 16)
        break;
}
bufferedReader.close();
```